# Recreational drugs by half life

Tags: biochemistry, chemical-biology

I am interested in the [Biological Half Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_half-life) of substances. In the previous wikipedia link, I've already found the half lives of common pharmaceutical products. I can't seem to find similar data for recreational substances, does anyone know these half lives?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise there was a biology beta. Does a pharmacology questions belong there? I don't know, flagged it.

Comment: I think it would need some elaboration to be worthy of migrating, to be honest.  I think as it is, it's okay here, but asking about specific *classes* of drugs would make it more scientific and rigorous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia reports biological half-lives for several recreational drugs I just tried (cocaine, THC, MDMA). In each case, I went to the page for the particular substance, and Wikipedia keeps an information box at the top of the article containing the pharmacokinetic data. THC's half-life has a citation to the scientific literature, while the other two I checked do not. I think it might be slightly harder in general to get good data for the purely recreational drugs. I would expect drugs without an accepted medical benefit to be less well-studied. To find what's there, though, it looks like you will be able to look up each active ingrediate individually. Depending on what you need, Wikipedia might be okay. If it's not, follow the Wikipedia citation back to the literature if it's there, or try PubMed.

Answer (score 2):

Try [DrugBank](http://www.drugbank.ca/). It's a comprehensive and free-to-use database for a large number of drugs. I saw it has data on Cocaine and Heroin (look in the pharmacology section).

(Yes, this question is three and a half years old, but it still may help someone...)

Comment: What is the maximum number of atoms in a DrugBank molecule? [Your answer is "three and a half years old" now ;) ]

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean...

Comment: You suggest using DrugBank. Most datasets provide information on the number and type of atoms (e.g, QM9 dataset is consist of 134000 molecules made of C,O,N,F and H with maximum 9 atoms in a molecule). Was wondering if you have those info and can add them to the answer.

Comment: Ok, well, I don't have that info, but even if I had it, I do not understand how it would be related to the original question.